# Integral with variable limits

Tags: matlab, variables, numerical-integration, nonlinear-functions

Hi im and struggling to solve an integral with a variable as the limit using matlab, the 2 biggest problems I have is that matlab can't find the integral explicitly and a lot of the numerical methods wont except variables

I need to solve

```
0=H/2R  - integral (z(x) between b and 1)

z(x)= (((x/((a*x*x)+1-a))^2)-1)^-0.5
b= (sin(t)+sqrt(t^2 + 4a(a-1)))/2a
```

I know H,R and t and the idea is to solve the integral then solve the nonlinear equation for a, I know to suse fzero/fsolve for the nonlinear equation but I am stuggling to solve the integral

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could try a shooting method - guess a value for a and numerically solve from there until you find an a value which solves the last equation.  Heres something that should work (though I guessed randomly at the numeric values and didn't get it to converge)

```
function test

    a_guess = .1
    fzero(@(a) solveWithA(a), a_guess)


    function res = solveWithA(a)

    t = .9;

    H = 1.5;
    R = 1.1;


    z = @(x) (((x/((a*x*x)+1-a))^2)-1)^-0.5;
    b = (sin(t)+sqrt(t^2 + 4*a*(a-1)))/(2*a);

    lower_limit = b;

    integrand = z;


    [T, Y] = ode45(@(t, x) integrand(x),[lower_limit 1],0);

    res = norm((H/2/R - Y(end)))

    end

end
```

But an analytic expression for a... I think its pen and paper :)  Try doing the indefinite integral by hand, then applying the limits? Though, removing a from the integrand still leaves a nasty result.  There's probably a 'trick' for this better posed on math overflow.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it has to be done in matlab, i wasnt sure if shooting could be used as its not really an IVP/BVP, why do you use norm at the end?

Comment: I used norm so that the imaginary part of the number is included in the error for fsolve :)

Comment: BTW - how did this problem come up?

Comment: Its to work out surface tension on a compressed cylinder, H is the height, R the radius and i need to solve to the equation for a to work out the surface tension, thats why im not sure whether their should be an imaginary part

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be imaginary... - I was just getting them with my random input values.  Of course make sure the values make physical sense :)